# Get the value of a model field as it is in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I do

```
>> a = Annotation.first
>> a.body
=> "?"
>> a.body = "hello"
=> "hello"
```

Now, I haven't saved `a` yet, so in the database its body is still `?`. How can I find out what `a`'s body was before I changed it?

I guess I could do `Annotation.find(a.id).body`, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way (e.g., one that doesn't do a DB query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a.body_was`

You can also check to see if it's dirty with `a.changed?` and/or `a.body_changed?`